# Python: calculate the magnetic field of a wire using biot-savart-law

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, physics

I want to calculate the magnetic field of a wire using biot-savart-law. Some people recommend to use numpy arrays. At first i did it with vpython and it worked. But know I want to use Matplotlib for visualisation. Therefore I need arrays right? But I stuck now.

I also posted this question to codereview, but they send me to stackoverflow.

The problem is in this line --> bfield2 = konstante*I*cross(dl, (rx,ry,rz))/r**3

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from visual import *

I = 1
mu0 = 1e-7
konstante = mu0/(4*np.pi)

# wire elements; always lenght one
coord = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0), (9,0), (9,1),
         (9,2), (9,3), (9,4), (9,5), (9,6), (9,7), (9,8)]
# draw the wires
#for i in range(len(coord)-1):
#    wire = curve(pos=(coord[i],coord[i+1]), radius=0.2)

# calculate the b-field
def bfield(x,y,z):
    bfield3 = 0
    # number of wire elements
    for i in range(len(coord)-1):
        # center of the wire element
        wiremiddlex = coord[i][0]+(coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0])/2.0
        wiremiddley = coord[i][1]+(coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1])/2.0
        wiremiddlez = 0
        rx = x-wiremiddlex
        ry = y-wiremiddley
        rz = 0
        r = (rx**2+ry**2+rz**2)**0.5
        dl = ((coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0]), (coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1]), 0)
        bfield2 = konstante*I*cross(dl, (rx,ry,rz))/r**3 # i have to use numpy arrays
        bfield3 += (bfield2[0]**2 + bfield2[1]**2 + bfield2[2]**2)**0.5
    return bfield3

# visualize
xwidth=10
ywidth=10
delta = 1
x = np.arange(0, xwidth, delta)
y = np.arange(0, ywidth, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
slicee = 3
Z = bfield(X,Y,slicee)

plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')
plt.show()
```

EDIT No. 7: I delete the other Edits. I don't want to confuse. The output in not correct. Please see the next Edit.

```
# Calculation of a magnetic field of a wire
# later I want to to it three dimensional

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

I = 10000000000
mu0 = 1e-7
constant = mu0/(4*np.pi)

# wire elements; always lenght one
coord = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0),
         (9,0), (9,1), (9,2), (9,3), (9,4), (9,5), (9,6), (9,7), (9,8),
         (8,8), (7,8), (6,8), (5,8)]

# calculate the b-field
def bfield(x,y,z):
    b2 = np.zeros((xwidth,ywidth))
    for x in range(xwidth):
        for y in range(ywidth):
            # number of wire elements
            for i in range(21):
                rx = (coord[i][0]+coord[i+1][0])/2. - x
                ry = (coord[i][1]+coord[i+1][1])/2. - y
                rz = z * 1.0 # = z-0
                r = (rx**2+ry**2+rz**2)**0.5 # distance r between field and middle of the wire
                dl = np.array([(coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0]), (coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1]), 0])
                b = np.cross(dl, np.array([rx,ry,rz]))
                e = constant*I*b/r**3
                b2[y][x] += e[2] # why not x y?
    return b2

xwidth = 15 
ywidth = 15
delay = 1
x = np.arange(0, xwidth, delay)
y = np.arange(0, ywidth, delay)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
slicee = 0.1
Z = bfield(X,Y,slicee)

# visualize
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
x1 = array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,8,7,6,5])
y1 = array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8])
plot(x1,y1)
plt.title('magnetic field')
plt.show()
```

Last edit:
Finally i did it without numpy.
The following version works.

```
# Calculation of a magnetic field of a wire
# later I want to to it three dimensional

import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *

# constant
I = 10000000000
mu0 = 1e-7
constant = mu0/(4*np.pi)

# wire position
coord = [(10,10), (20,10), (20,20), (10,20), (10,25)]
coord2 = []

# devide path of the wire in parts of length one
parts = 0
for n in range(len(coord)-1):
    lengthx = coord[n+1][0] - coord[n][0]
    lengthy = coord[n+1][1] - coord[n][1]
    length = (lengthx**2 + lengthy**2)**.5
    for m in range(int(length)):
        coord2.append((coord[n][0]+lengthx/length*m, coord[n][1]+lengthy/length*m))
        parts += 1

# calculate the b-field
def bfield(x,y,z):
    b = 0
    for i in range(parts-1):
        dlx = coord2[i+1][0]-coord2[i][0]
        dly = coord2[i+1][1]-coord2[i][1] 
        dlz = 0
        dl = np.array([dlx,dly,dlz])
        rspace_minus_rwire_x = x - (coord2[i][0]+dlx)
        rspace_minus_rwire_y = y - (coord2[i][1]+dly)
        rspace_minus_rwire_z = z - 0
        rspace_minus_rwire = np.array([rspace_minus_rwire_x, rspace_minus_rwire_y, rspace_minus_rwire_z])
        absr = (rspace_minus_rwire_x**2 + rspace_minus_rwire_y**2 + rspace_minus_rwire_z**2)**0.5
        a = constant * I * np.cross(dl, rspace_minus_rwire) / absr**3
        b += (a[0]**2 + a[1]**2 + a[2]**2)**0.5
    return b

xwidth = 26
ywidth = 26
z = 1
bmatrix = np.zeros((xwidth,ywidth))
for x in range(xwidth):
    for y in range(ywidth):
        bmatrix[x][y] = bfield(x,y,z)

# visualize
plt.figure()
x = range(xwidth)
y = range(ywidth)
z = bmatrix[x][y].T
contour(x,y,z,35)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem :) ?

Comment: What's the problem you're having with that line?

Comment: I dont know how to use the array.

Comment: I posted the error that I get.

Comment: In the revised code (Edit 3), you've set bfield3 = 0 at the top of def bfield, so you can't call it as an array-like object. If you intended to use the bfield3 that you set up at the very top of the code snippet, then you have some scoping issues. Also, the way you set up bfield3 at the top of the code is very inefficient. Just use the np.zeros method to create a array filled with zeros of an arbitrary size

Comment: @kame: in your last version you are not harnessing all the `numpy` power. You have too many (unnessary) loops. When to code comes shorter, it cames also most more clear what you are trying to achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
dl = ((coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0]), (coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1]), 0)
bfield2 = konstante*I*cross(dl, (rx,ry,rz))/r**3 # i have to use numpy arrays
```

To

```
dl = np.array([(coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0]), (coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1]), 0])
bfield2 = konstante*I*cross(dl, np.array([rx,ry,rz]))/r**3 # i have to use numpy arrays
```

I don't have Numpy on this machine, so this is untested.  Basically, change your tuples into a numpy arrays using [`np.array`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

You could probably also leave `dl` alone and change `bfield2` to use `np.array(dl)` instead of `dl`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not any answer tou your original question, but just a hint how to operate with `numpy` arrays:

```
In []: coord = [(0,0), (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0), (5,0), (6,0), (7,0), (8,0), (9,0), (9,1), (9,2), (9,3), (9,4), (9,5), (9,6), (9,7), (9,8)]
In []: coord= np.array(coord).T
In []: coord
Out[]:
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
In [170]: wiremiddle= (coord[:, 1:]- coord[:, :-1])/ 2.
In []: wiremiddle
Out[]:
array([[ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. , 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. , 0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  0.5, 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0.5]])
```

I'll hope this will help to rewrite your code.

Answer (score 1):

you do this:

```
bfield3 = 0
```

maybe you should do something like this:

```
bfield3 = np.zeros((len(...),len(...)))
```

Or maybe bfield3 is allocated already? and you just want to set all values to zero? Then do this:

```
bfield3[:,:] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid bringing in the visual module, which it appears you are using only for the call to 'cross' and use numpy's cross in its place:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html

You'll have to change a couple of lines to make dl and the second argument of cross numpy arrays

```
 dl = np.array([(coord[i+1][0]-coord[i][0]), (coord[i+1][1]-coord[i][1]), 0])
```

and double check to make sure that numpy's cross is doing the same thing that visual's was.

If you insist on using the visual cross method, then it is clear from the error that you're having a type conflict which you'll have to resolve